# Group a Ruby Array of Dates by Month and Year into a Hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, date, hash

Let's say I had a Ruby Array of `Date`s like:

```
2011-01-20
2011-01-23
2011-02-01
2011-02-15
2011-03-21
```

What would be an easy and Ruby-esque way of creating a Hash that groups the Date elements by year and then month, like:

```
{
    2011 => {
        1   => [2011-01-20, 2011-01-23],
        2   => [2011-02-01, 2011-02-15],
        3  => [2011-03-21],
    }
}
```

I can do this by iterating over everything and extracting years, months and so on, then comining them.

Ruby offers so many methods and blocks for Arrays and Hashes, there must be an easier way?

Comment: You should not put `0` in front of the months in the hash unless you intend to express them as octal. Either way, if the hash is the inspected form, `0` should not appear.

Comment: @sawa Thanks, I was just making this up and forgot about that. It's not actual paste data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
require 'date'

dates = [
  '2011-01-20',
  '2011-01-23',
  '2011-02-01',
  '2011-02-15',
  '2011-03-21'
].map{|sd| Date.parse(sd)}

Hash[
  dates.group_by(&:year).map{|y, items|
    [y, items.group_by{|d| d.strftime('%B')}]
  }
]
#=> {2011=>{"January"=>[#<Date: 2011-01-20 (4911163/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-01-23 (4911169/2,0,2299161)>], "February"=>[#<Date: 2011-02-01 (4911187/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-02-15 (4911215/2,0,2299161)>], "March"=>[#<Date: 2011-03-21 (4911283/2,0,2299161)>]}}
```

I noticed you have changed month names into numbers, so you may want to replace `d.strftime('%B')` above with `d.month` or whatever else.

Here's a step-by-step explanation:

You essentially want two-level grouping: first level by year, second by month. Ruby has very useful method `group_by`, which groups elements by given expression (a block). So: first part is grouping original array by `year`:

```
hash_by_year = dates.group_by(&:year)
# => {2011=>[#<Date: 2011-01-20 (4911163/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-01-23 (4911169/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-02-01 (4911187/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-02-15 (4911215/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-03-21 (4911283/2,0,2299161)>]}
```

That gives us first level: keys are years, values arrays of dates with given year. But we still need to group the second level: that's why we map by-year hash - to group its values by `month`. Let's for start forget `strftime` and say that we're grouping by `d.month`:

```
hash_by_year.map{|year, dates_in_year|
  [year, dates_in_year.group_by(&:month)]
}
# => [[2011, {1=>[#<Date: 2011-01-20 (4911163/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-01-23 (4911169/2,0,2299161)>], 2=>[#<Date: 2011-02-01 (4911187/2,0,2299161)>, #<Date: 2011-02-15 (4911215/2,0,2299161)>], 3=>[#<Date: 2011-03-21 (4911283/2,0,2299161)>]}]]
```

That way we got our second level grouping. Instead of array of all dates in a year, now we have hash whose keys are months, and values arrays of dates for a given month.

The only problem we have is that `map` returns an array and not a hash. Thats why we "surround" whole expression by `Hash[]`, which makes a hash out of array of pairs, in our case pairs `[year, hash_of_dates_by_month]`.

Sorry if the explanation sounds confusing, I found harder to explain functional expressions than imperative, because of the nesting. :(

Comment: Seems like the best solution! As I'm relatively new to Ruby, I would very much appreciate a small explanation of what each function does!

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is a very good answer. Will probably help a few more people in the future!

Answer (score 1):

This gets you pretty close, you just need to change the numerical month number into a textual month name:

```
dates = %w(
2011-01-20
2011-01-23
2011-02-01
2011-02-15
2011-03-21
)

grouped = dates.inject({}) do |ret, date|
  y,m,d = date.split('-')
  ret[y] ||= {}
  # Change 'm' into month name here
  ret[y][m] ||= []
  ret[y][m] << date
  ret
end

puts grouped.inspect
```

Comment: I capitalized Date in my OP because I use Ruby's `Date` object, not Strings. I'll look into it though!

Comment: Oh, my mistake. The same inject concept should work, but you won't have to call `split` to get the date components.

Answer (score 1):

```
dates = %w(
2011-01-20
2011-01-23
2011-02-01
2011-02-15
2011-03-21
)
hash = {}
dates.each do |date|
   year, month = date.strftime('%Y,%B').split(',')
   hash[year] ||= {}
   hash[year][month] = hash[year][month].to_a << date
end
```