# How to list @objects2 under sorted @objects1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, model-view-controller

The below correctly lists the `@routines` on the current day, BUT only if there is a `lifetime.deadline` present for the current day.

Is there a way we can list all the `@routines` for the current day even if no `lifetime` exists?

**controller**

```
@lifetime_deadlines = current_user.lifetimes.deadline_present.order("deadline ASC")
@lifetime_years = @lifetime_deadlines.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_year }
@routines = current_user.routines.unarchived.committed_for_today.incomplete.order(:order)
```

**view**

```
<% @lifetime_years.sort.each do |year, lifetimes| %>
  <%= year.strftime('%Y') %>
  <% lifetimes.group_by { |t| t.deadline.beginning_of_month }.sort.each do |month, lifetime| %>
    <%= month.strftime('%B') %>
    <% for lifetime in lifetimes %>
      <%= lifetime.deadline %>: <%= lifetime.name %>
    <% end %>

    <% @routines.each do |routine| %>
      <% if lifetime.deadline == Date.current %>
        <p><%= routine.action %></p>
      <% else %>
        NONE
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**End Result with Current Code**

```
2016
  January
    18: Run a Marathon (aka lifetime object)
    25: Eat a piece of poop (aka lifetime object)
  February
    7: Resolve SO Question (aka lifetime object)
    7: Journal (aka routine object) #This routine object only shows though if a lifetime object is set for current day.
  March
    5: Write a Book (aka lifetime object)
```

**End Result With Your Help**

```
2016
  January
    18: Run a Marathon (aka lifetime object)
    25: Eat a piece of poop (aka lifetime object)
  February
    2: Resolve SO Question (aka lifetime object)
    7: Journal (aka routine object) #Always shows even if a lifetime challenge is not set for the current day.
  March
    5: Write a Book (aka lifetime object)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood the question completely but I believe you are looking to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN lifetimes` instead of an inner join. You might want to add your models to the question as we have no idea about what your buisness logic and relations are.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to stuff the collections into an array and sort by date:

```
all = (@a + @b).sort {|a,b| a.deadline <=> b.deadline }
```

From that you might want to create a hash grouped by the month:

```
all = Hash[ 
       all.group_by { |i| i.deadline.month }
         #converts month number to name
         .map{|m,a| [I18n.t("date.month_names")[m], a] } 
      ]
```

---

```
{
  "March" => [<obj>,<obj>],
  "January" => [<obj>,<obj>,<obj>,<obj>]
}
```

You would then iterate through the hash and the items in the array:

```
<% all.each_with_index do |(month, items)| %>
  <p><%= month %></p>
  <ul>
    <% items.each do |i| %>
      <li><b><%= i.deadline.day %></b><%= i.action %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I don't think there is really a *Rails way* of doing this except with polymorphic relationships as you want to pull extremely inhomogeneous collections and then iterate though it as it where one collection.

Comment: I'm not even sure I have understood what you are trying to do - and this is meant more as a nudge in the correct direction than a complete answer.

Comment: See this question if you need it span across years as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639921/group-a-ruby-array-of-dates-by-month-and-year-into-a-hash

Comment: Thanks Max! I'm struggling with `all = (@lifetimes + @routines).sort {|a| a.deadline <=> b.created_at }`. I put that in the controller, but I'm getting the error, `undefined local variable or method 'b' `

Comment: Oops, forgot one of the block arguments. Should be `.sort {|a,b| a.deadline <=> b.created_at }`. Edited

Comment: Thanks I've been trying that, but we get `undefined method 'deadline' for #<Routine:0x007ff319eba438>` for `all = (@a + @b).sort {|a,b| a.deadline <=> b.created_at }`

Comment: I made `@a = current_user.lifetimes` and `@b = current_user.routines`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102921/discussion-between-max-and-anthonygalli-com).